# On Mac OS X, can I use Cmd + 1(to 9) keys to switch between tabs in Terminal?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, terminal, shortcuts

On Mac OS X, can I use  Cmd + 1(to 9) keys to switch between tabs in Terminal? Right now it switches between Terminal "Windows" but I like the tabs better.

I know I can use Cmd + [ or Cmd + ] to go left and right, but I just wish this was the same as my web browser.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/), it will do exactly that.

> iTerm2 is a replacement for Terminal and the successor to iTerm. It works on Macs with Leopard or Snow Leopard. Its focus is on performance, internationalization, and supporting innovative features that make your life better.

Basically, you just get a lot more settings, also see the "Navigation Shortcuts" in the image below.

[image]